# Replace 0 from mod function with the divisor

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, modulo

```
if mod(m,18) == 0
   mm = 18;
else
   mm = mod(m,18);
end
```

How can I accomplish this in one line by simply using the `mod` function and some arithmetic? Above code is running within a `for` loop and `m` is the iterator.

Result should be:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
.
.
.
17 -> 17
18 -> 18
19 -> 1
20 -> 2
.
.
36 -> 18
37 -> 1
.
```

Comment: `mm=mod(m-1,18)+1` ?

Comment: I guess you'll have to clarify what to do with `36`. Do you want `36` to show up as `36`, or as `18`?

Comment: @Adriaan All multiples of `18` would be `18` including `36`. `mod(m-1,18)+1` works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`mod`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) has array support, so you do not need a loop:

```
data = 1:n;
tmp = mod(data,18);
tmp(tmp==0) = 18; % Set all numbers divisible by 18 to 18
% tmp(tmp==0) = 18*(1:floor(n/18)); % Set all numbers divisible by 18 to their original
```

The solution [rahnema1 provided in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413526/replace-0-from-mod-function-with-the-divisor/52413648#comment91771079_52413526) works better indeed, I just want to show that in case you want multiples of 18 to show up as their original value instead of 18 that's easily done by this code as well:

```
mm=mod(m-1,18)+1
mm(mm==18) = 18*(1:floor(n/18));
```

---

Another way to create the same array is to use `repmat` instead of `mod`:

```
N=100; % total array length
n=18; %
m=1:n;
mm=repmat(m,[1 ceil(N/n)]);
mm=mm(1:N); % chop off remainer
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
mm = mod(m,18);
mm(mm==0)=18;
```

Comment: How's this different from my answer, which was posted 20 hours before yours? Besides, why should I "try this"? *Explain* why a solution works instead.

Comment: @Adriaan, My impression is that I answer to the person who asked the question. You do not need to try anything. To me I rather not define an unnecessary tmp variable. The first comment has more neat solution, so please discard mine.

Comment: Partial yes; the direct answer is to the person who answered, but Stack Overflow strives to be a knowledge database. This requires people to be able to find and understand an answer in the future as well, hence it's best to explain why a piece of code works. As to the differences between your and my code: I called `m=data;mm=tmp`, no temporary variables involved. Finally: I can *disregard* your answer, *discarding*, i.e. deleting it, can only be done by you by pressing the "delete" button under the answer, that's up to you whether to do that or not.